# Auto suggestion not working with JSP include

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am trying to include another page("EHSiteHeadHome.jsp") in my page("AddExceptionAssetID.jsp").I also want to include autosuggestion in my page. Autosuggestion is working perfectly if I am not including other page but with other page, it is not working. Actually Ajax call is not happening with jsp:include.

**AddExceptionAssetID.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Exception</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


 
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#AssetID").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "AssetAutocomplete",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {
                        term: request.term
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<%--     <jsp:include page="EHSiteHeadHome.jsp" /> --%>
  <%--  this is where I am facing problem
 --%>  
  <div class="module mx-auto my-auto" style="margin:20px 10px 10px 20px">
 
 <div class="container" style="margin-top:180px">
     <span id="ErrorMsg" style="margin-left:100px;color:red;font-weight:bold;">${msg} 
</span>
<form class="form"  action="AddException" method="post">
    
     <div class="form-group row">
       <label for="AssetID" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm"> Asset ID: </label>
       <input type="text" style="width:150px;" class="form-control  col-sm-4 form-control-sm col-form-label-sm" id="AssetID" name="AssetID"   onkeyup="showData(this.value);">
    </div>  
    <input type="submit" value="CheckAsset" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="AddException"  >

      
  </form>
 
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EHSiteHeadHome.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Site Head</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body {
 font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #fff; font-weight: 100px;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
}

.btco-menu li > a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #000;
  
}

.btco-menu .active a:focus,
.btco-menu li a:focus ,
.navbar > .show > a:focus{
    background: transparent;
    outline: 0;
    background-color: darkgray;
}

.dropdown-menu .show > .dropdown-toggle::after{
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
i{
 margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
</style>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top  navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-md bg-dark navbar-light  text-white btco-menu " style="background-color: #696969;color: white;  ">

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="EHSiteHeadHome.jsp">
        <img src="img/Brand.PNG" style=" height: 50px; width: 80px;border-radius: 15%;">
    </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item ">
                <!-- <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> -->
            </li>
           
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://bootstrapthemes.co" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-bars"> Menu</i> </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  
                     <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="far fa-handshake" style="margin: 0 13px 0 0;"></i> Exception</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="AddExceptionAssetID.jsp"> <i class="fas fa-user-plus" style="margin: 0 5px 0 0;"></i>  Add</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="UpdateException.jsp"> <i class="fas fa-edit" style="margin: 0 5px 0 0;"></i> Update</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="RemoveException.jsp"> <i class="fas fa-trash" style="margin: 0 15px 0 0;"></i>Remove</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="DownloadException.jsp"> <i class="fa fa-download" style="margin: 0 15px 0 0;"></i>Download Evidence</a></li>
                            
                        </ul>
                    </li> 
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="fas fa-book" style="margin: 0 13px 0 0;"></i> Reports</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="ReportExceptionSiteHead.jsp"> <i class="far fa-check-circle" style="margin: 0 10px 0 0;"></i> View All Records</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="ReportExceptionSiteHeadFiltered.jsp"> <i class="far fa-check-circle" style="margin: 0 10px 0 0;"></i> View Filetered Reports</a></li> 
                       </ul>
                   <!--  </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#"> <i class="fas fa-wrench" style="margin: 0 10px 0 0;"></i> Add Metadata </a>                       
                    </li> -->
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style="float:right;">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <p class="nav-link" href="#" style="padding-right: 20px"><i class="fas fa-user-circle">Site Head &nbsp &nbsp<%= session.getAttribute("activeUser") %> </i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="Logout.jsp" style="padding-right: 20px"><i class="fas fa-power-off"></i> </a>
            </li>
            <!--<li class="nav-item"><a  href="#">User</a>
            <li class="nav-item"><a  href="#">Logout</a>-->
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
<script>
    $( document ).ready( function () {
    $( '.navbar a.dropdown-toggle' ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        var $el = $( this );
        var $parent = $( this ).offsetParent( ".dropdown-menu" );
        $( this ).parent( "li" ).toggleClass( 'show' );

        if ( !$parent.parent().hasClass( 'navbar-nav' ) ) {
            $el.next().css( { "top": $el[0].offsetTop, "left": $parent.outerWidth() - 4 } );
        }
        $( '.navbar-nav li.show' ).not( $( this ).parents( "li" ) ).removeClass( "show" );
        return false;
    } );
} );
</script>
<span id="ErrorMsg" style="margin-left:100px;color:red;font-weight:bold;">${msg} 
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

**AjaxAutocomplete.java**

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import dao.DBConnector;

 /**
  * Servlet implementation class AssetAutocomplete
 */
 @WebServlet("/AssetAutocomplete")
 public class AssetAutocomplete extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public AssetAutocomplete() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("INSIDE AUTOCOMPLTE SERVLET");
    String term = request.getParameter("term");
    System.out.println("Data from ajax call " + term);
    Connection con=DBConnector.getConnector();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String data;
    try {
        String ch=term+"%";
        ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tbl_asset  WHERE AssetID  LIKE '"+ch+"'");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            data = rs.getString("AssetID");
            System.out.println("DATA: "+data);
            list.add(data);
        }

        System.out.println(list);
        String json=null;
        json = new Gson().toJson(list);
        response.getWriter().write(json );
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

*AjaxAutocomplete.java is the java servlet from where ajax is requesting data*

Comment: the problem must be with addition of `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js` in included page. By this way jquery is getting added twice and `$(document).ready(function()` present within master page is not getting invoked. Please modify your child page so that it will include jQuery only if its not present or downloaded previously on page.